# calculate new mean using old mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, mean

I had a dataset `df`that looked like this:

```
Value         themes     country    date
-1.975767     Weather    Brazil     2022-02-13
-0.540979     Fruits     China      2022-02-13
-2.359127     Fruits     China      2022-02-13
-2.815604     Corona     China      2022-02-13
-0.712323     Weather    UK         2022-02-13
-0.929755     Weather    Brazil     2022-02-13
```

I grouped themes+country to calculate mean and count values of each combination of theme and country (eg: Weather, Brazil or Weather, UK)

```
df_calculations = df.groupby(["themes", "country"], as_index = False)["value"].mean()
df_calculations['count'] = df.groupby(["themes", "country"])["value"].count().tolist()
```

Then I added this info to a new table `df_avg` that looks like this:

```
country    type       mean     count     last_checked_date
Brazil     Weather     x       2         2022-02-13    #same for all rows
Brazil     Corona      y                 2022-02-13
China      Corona      z       1         2022-02-13
China      Fruits      s       2         2022-02-13
```

However, now, there's new  are additional rows in the same original `df`.

```
Value         themes     country    date
-1.975560     Weather    Brazil     2022-02-15
-0.540123     Fruits     China      2022-02-16
-2.359234     Fruits     China      2022-02-16
-2.359234     Corona     UK         2022-02-16
```

I want to go through the `df` rows who's date is after the `last_checked_date`.

Then I want to calculate a new mean for each combination again but using the old mean and n value from my `df_avg`table instead of re-calculating for the whole `df`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this: [Calculate new mean from old mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784874/how-to-calculate-new-mean-if-population-is-unknown)

Since you are maintaining a count (if not, it is pretty trivial) you can use that along with existing mean to calculate updated mean using the new observation.